# Create screenshot of page from HTML code

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I have the HTML content of a page and would like to programmatically take a screenshot of it. I dont have the original URL - just the contents of it.

Is there any way to do this?

Thanks,
Yannis

Comment: open the contents in a web browser rather than notepad..?

Comment: Ehm - I mean programmatically...Hence the node.js / phantomjs tags

Answer (score 1):

You can set the content of the page as string.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.content = '<html><body><p>Welcome to the Dark Side!</p></body></html>';
page.render('screenshont.png');
```

Answer (score 0):

In phantomjs you can call [page.render](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/render.html)("screenshot.png") function.

Since you have the html code only, and not the url, to create "page" out of html you can do something like this:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open("file:///C://Full/Path/To/test.html", function start(status) {
  page.render('screenshont.png');
  phantom.exit();
});
```